# local storage iteration get the value of clicked button inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
                var dataNya = JSON.parse(localStorage.key(i));
                // console.log(dataNya);
                var displayUlit = "";
                    displayUlit += "<br/>";
                var spaceTo = "";
                    spaceTo += " || ";
                console.log(dataNya);
                    var keme = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
                $("#pangDisplay").append(dataNya + spaceTo + "<button class='pangEdit' value="+dataNya+">"+JSON.parse(keme)+"</button>" + "  " + displayUlit);
                console.log(JSON.parse(keme));
                // localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(dataNya), JSON.stringify("complete"));
            }
            $(".pangEdit").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var pangInput = $(".pangEdit").val();
                console.log(pangInput);
                localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(pangInput), JSON.stringify("complete"));
            });
```

i want to get the key of the localstorage where i can pass the data and update its value. help me thanks

Comment: what your localStorage looks like

Comment: it has a two column. which is the key and the value.

Comment: key - task and value - status for example: task: cleaning. status: pending

Comment: add pls to u question

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attached `data` attributes in jQuery for this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var dataNya = localStorage.key(i);

    var displayUlit = "";
    displayUlit += "<br/>";

    var spaceTo = "";
    spaceTo += " || ";

    var keme = localStorage.getItem(dataNya);
    var button = "<button class='pangEdit' data-storagekey='" + dataNya + "' value='" + dataNya + "'>" + keme + "</button>";
    $("#pangDisplay").append(dataNya + spaceTo + button + "  " + displayUlit);
}

$(".pangEdit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataNya = $(this).data('storagekey');

    localStorage.setItem(dataNya, "complete");
});
```